# Setting a class's values with multiple queries

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a class that has Title, users and a timestamp.

My database is set up like :

```
users
  ablksjdlf39493 
     rooms
       room1: true



 rooms
   room1
      timestampOfLastPost: 39403942
      users
         039403fsjlkj: true
         ;alkjsdksdkj: true
```

I'm running a query on my user's rooms and grabbing the snapshot.key to get in this example "room1". Then inside of the first query I run another query and I use that key as a child reference to my rooms node to go to that room (rooms-->room1), and set is as my class object's title. From the 2nd query I'm pulling out the timestamp and use that for my object's timestamp.

I'm a bit confused how to get the childcount of out users.

I was running yet another nested query inside of my second query. But then I was getting all sorts of weird duplicate posts being added to my tableview when I was loading them. And that just doesn't seem very efficient anyways.

Is there a way in my second query to get both the timestamp and the children.count of my users node? The only way I've seen to do that is to run an observer on the specific node and do a `snapshot.childrenCount`.

edit:

```
currentUserFirebaseReference.child("rooms").observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        self.interestsArray = []

 if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                let eachInterest = Interest()
                let interestKey = snap.key
                let title = snap.key.uppercaseString
                eachInterest.title = title
  //grabbing the user's current rooms and getting the snap.key to use for my next query.
    DataService.ds.REF_INTERESTS.child(interestKey).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

if let lastuser = snapshot.value!["lastJoin"] as? Int {
                        eachInterest.latestUser = lastuser
                        } else {
                        print("couln't pull that value")

                    }
   //getting the timestamp 

                    DataService.ds.REF_INTERESTS.child(interestKey).child("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

 // I can get the users children.count by doing yet another query, but my 
 // interestsArray gets all messed up and I get duplicates / weird 
 // loading in my tableview. So I'm looking to not do this whole 
 // separate query and just grab it from up above where I get the 
 // timestamp? 


                  let snapshotChildren = String(Int(snapshot.childrenCount))


                        eachInterest.users = snapshotChildren

                        self.interestsArray.append(eachInterest)

 //self.interestsArray.sortInPlace({ $0.latestUser < $1.latestUser })

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                    })
               })


            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want? That was a bit confusing...Mayb just to me... :D

Comment: Sorry lol. I'm making a like Post class object with the variables of title,timestamp, and usercount basically. 

If we look at my rooms node up top, the title I'm needing is the "room1" which is the snapshot.key, got that. the timestamp is the timestampOfLastPost, got that. But then I need the childcount of "users" and I don't know how to access that without making a whole new query but it seems like I should be able to just grab it right then n' there.

Comment: Give the code to where you are doing all of this,....

Comment: posted it @Dravidian

Comment: @Dravidian So where I'm setting the timestamp, at that point in my my rooms---> room1 node. 

instead of making a whole other query to get under my "users" under the room1 node, is there a way to just get the children.count of snapshot.value["users"] right under where I'm setting the timestamp?

Comment: This far , what i understand is that your are listening to rooms node to just get the key and its timestamp. and then check if a specific user is using that room and if he does then...... This is where you lost me..Again. children.count of whom those users who have room1 in there rooms node OR children.count of all the users?

Comment: I'm listening to my users node child of "rooms" to use to iterate through my main "rooms" node. So if  a user had room 1 2 and 3 under their user node, I'd use those keys to go through room 1 2 and 3 in the main node via the "interestKey". At that point I'm grabbing the title "room1", the timestamp, ["lastJoin"], and then I need the amount of users in the room, so the amount of users under the rooms->room1->users node. @Dravidian